# Calculator final output issue

Tags: android, calculator

I am creating a calculator app in android. It should calculate anonymously whatever is on textBox. For e.g. I enter 1+2.5-5*8 in textBox. But when I call addition method the app gets crashed. Because the input is in string format and answer I want is in numeric format. I used string buffer. I tried in java that when I enter (1+1+3-1) in stringBuffer and I display using println() method it give correct answer but same does not happen with string buffer when I take that value from editText.

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert string into integer or float.

Use Integer.parseInt("") method to covert to integer and Float.parseFloat("") to convert to float.

Comment: Yes I tried this. The application gets crashed with NumberFormatException. Because the input text is (1 + 1.2 - 8) which is string in the beginning . but the whole string cannot be directly converted in number format.

Comment: Yes @Avinash so first of all you have to split the string and get the numbers out of that string. After extracting numbers, then use parseInt method and then do operations on them

Answer (score 0):

First of all welcome to StackOverFlow

It might help if you add code and the error log in the question

So I am gonna cover all the possible things that might be happening wrong in your program:

1. NumberFormatException- you might not be converting the string "12" into int 12 to do so use Interger.parseInt(your string buffer with number only here);
2. Try using a stack and a queue for your solution (google it you will get details)
3. You might be making a mistake in getting string from edittext it sometimes give NullPointerException

if above is not enough comment and add your code asap